# CMake: include external library headers

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have this snippet and it works fine:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries( myproj Qt5::Core )
target_include_directories( myproj PRIVATE ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

because I want to use [Qwt](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/). Now I run `find_library( LIB_qwt qwt )` and get the path to the `.so` in a breeze. But how do I get the header path and add it to `target_include_directories()`?

Also do I really need to manually include Qt? If I don't (but I include Qwt files in an ugly way) the headers of Qwt break compilation by not discovering Qt.

This is my Qwt installation: `libqwt-qt5-dev`.

Comment: I would use this [FindQwt.cmake](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindQwt.cmake) file and just do this: `target_link_libraries( myproj PRIVATE Qt5::core qwt::qwt )`. And you don't need to to do `target_include_directories(...)` since the include directories are declared in the `Qt5::core` target.

Comment: @kanstar use as in copy-paste it in my project?

Comment: Usually you would include that file into your project. Add that file to a directory in your project tree, e.g. `cmake/Modules` and add that path to the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` in your main `CMakeLists.txt` like `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake/Modules")`.

Comment: Of course you have to first do `find_package( Qwt )` before using `target_link_libraries(...)`.

Comment: @kanstar it worked with a similar cmake [file](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/cmake/FindQwt.cmake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add `${LIB_qwt_INCLUDE_DIR}` or `${QWT_INCLUDE_DIR}` to `target_include_directories` after `find_library( LIB_qwt qwt )`. You must include Qt manually.

If that doesn't work you can search for the path yourself, you could use `find_path` like so:

```
find_path(QWT_INCLUDE_DIR qwt.h)
target_include_directories( myproj PRIVATE ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${QWT_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

`qwt.h` must be somewhere on the path obviously.